# Can I stop VSCode Remote Server re-installing itself when I connect via SSH?

Tags: vscode-remote

I have got VSCode Remote via SSH working successfully between my Mac client and our Centos server. Our server is not online by default and I have to manually set proxies for it to download the Server.
VSCode Server wants to re-wget itself every now and then when I connect. When it does I need to kill the connection, set the proxies and reconnect to allow it to download the Server files.

My question: Is this wget procedure required (i.e. important updates) or can I bypass it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IME, the remote toolchain stuff is fairly hard-coded, so I'd be surprised if there was a clean solution. You might want to just alias `wget` (for the remote connection user) to some script which does enough to satisfy VSCode.

Comment: @Sneftel Thanks very much, I'll give it a try.